# Problem with rewriting toTS React HOC which limits visibility

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have React HOC which restricts component visibility based on fixed prop

```
const RenderWhenIsVisible = Component => {
    return function (props) {
        let { isVisible, ...newProps } = props;
        return props.isVisible ? <Component {...newProps} /> : null;
    };
};
```

When try to rewrite to TS errors appear. Below is the version with lowest errors number, in the meantime I have passed through few others

```
interface isVisible {
    isVisible: boolean;
}
function RenderWhenIsVisible<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
    return function (props: T & isVisible ) {
        let { isVisible, ...newProps} = props;
        return props.isVisible ? <Component {...newProps } /> : null;
    };
}
```

The error is:

> Type 'Omit<T & isVisible, "isVisible">' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & T & { children?: ReactNode; }'.   Type 'Omit<T
> & isVisible, "isVisible">' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Omit<T & isVisible, "isVisible">'.

I understand that ...newProps shoud be clearly typed as T but have no idea how to pass such the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limits to what TypeScript can reason about when it's still dealing with unresolved type parameters such as `T` and conditional types such as `Omit`.

There are ways to get around this, in this case I would recommend, since we expect `T` and `Omit<T & IsVisible, keyof IsVisible>` to be the same type,  to type the component as accepting either of those two types using a union. This shouldn't have a negative impact on the call site, and we can use `newProps` without any other issues:

```
interface IsVisible {
    isVisible: boolean;
}
function RenderWhenIsVisible<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T | Omit<T & IsVisible, keyof IsVisible>>) {
    return function (props: T & IsVisible ) {
        let { isVisible, ...newProps} = props;
        return props.isVisible ? <Component {...newProps } /> : null;
    };
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFB3AB2MWUBeWcAkqgGrCrAARgBsOAbxpwpcfnwEisALjiCIEUcgYBuGgF8aBAK4N8wCA0xYGAExYB1ABZXucoaIA8AFQB8ACgDCJJAMVjDK2HgwAHSB4OahngCeYFhecAA+cADyIMAwaQBkXLz8blgANHAA1liJEATFrgre3gCUcBLScJQwhlAWRiYwZha+YMRgqMqecEUupQpw7Z1d0qLwYjIl8qKVUfshAO4AChOounAAvHDjEJM6q9I9fRa3k1GyC6JwAPxw7rFgqEOvsokdTnd0BcAPTeODKBiGYTCB7SXQ6fQGYymcxwTxYVAwMbKTYMZAgJRwQlQRgAc10y0k3SwvX6-zh7lhejo6zxBJgdjyDiawGEeUSV0sNnsTgY8x2WF8+MJrSAA)